# Need to connect SSIS to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: ssis, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to take a file from Google Cloud Storage and load it in to SQL using SSIS.  I have no clue how to do this and I have not been able to find anything on how this can be done? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I know there are paid solutions for integrating with google,
https://www.cdata.com/drivers/google/ssis/

Not sure about the reverse way but during some of my search, I have found that:
Google Cloud Storage has an API:

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api-overview

I imagine you would end up with a Script Task component calling API

Comment: https://github.com/acropolium/SharpGs
I think this may have download/upload capabilities.
Check the demo