# How to connect SSIS to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ssis, gcloud

Does anyone know how do I connect Google Cloud Platform to `SSIS`?

To be more specific, How shall a token be created in `SSIS` that points to the google `0auth` in a project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435402/need-to-connect-ssis-to-google-cloud-storage

Comment: Remove SSIS from the equation - how would I connect to google cloud from a .NET 4.7 framework app? That same answer is going to apply to SSIS as a script Task/Component with the potential additional hurdle of installing nuget packages to the Global Assembly Cache, GAC.